# InvokeDynamic for Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, invokedynamic

Is it possible to use InvokeDynamic for Grails?

If so, what versions of Grails, Java, etc. are compatible?

What is the procedure to set it up?

If it's not possible, when might InvokeDynamic support be added to Grails 2.x and/or 3.x?

I haven't found any recent information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support was added in Grails 3 (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/3366). The Groovy documentation lays out how to use it (http://www.groovy-lang.org/indy.html).

Comment: Do you know if InvokeDynamic support will be added to any Grails 2.x versions?  Also, do you know the performance benefit that InvokeDynamic provides?

Comment: We were not using indy with Grails, but with a Groovy-based library. We had mixed results regarding the performance value of turning it on.